# Calculating Volume using the Shell Method

Tags: calculus, volume

[image]

Hey I'm trying to do this problem by taking the integral from $0$ to $1$ of $2\pi{x}(x^4-(x^{1/4})dx$ and my answer comes out to $2\pi(\dfrac{1}{6} - \dfrac{4}{9})$ but that answer is incorrect. Can anyone help?

Comment: Draw a picture. The curve $y=x^{1/4}$ is *above* the curve $y=x^4$ in our interval.

Comment: Note that $\sqrt[4]{x} \geq x^4$ when $0 \leq x \leq 1$. Remember, we're trying to find a volume, so your answer should be positive - that'll be your first clue that something is wrong with your answer you gave here!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On the interval $[0,1]$, $x^{1/4}\geq x^4$. Hence the shell method yields:
$$V=2\pi\int^1_0x(x^\frac{1}{4}-x^4)dx\\
\implies V=2\pi\left[\frac{4x^{\frac{9}{4}}}{9}-\frac{x^6}{6}\right]^1_0$$

Comment: Wow I can't believe I missed that, thank you

Comment: @Shenuque Sure!